# Bug with colors loading from xacro in Gazebo 7

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In my model.xacro file there is:

```
<gazebo reference="top_plate">
  <material> Gazebo/Black </material>
</gazebo>
```

And I only get an white model. If I Edit the model in Gazebo7 and write 'Gazebo/Black' in Visusal/Material/Scrip/Name it works. I want it to be black while loarding. Has someboady an idea how to fix this bug.

My launch file:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<!-- Note: the world_name is with respect to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environmental variable -->

  <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/empty.world"/> 
  <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  <extra_gazebo_args value="verbose" />
</include>


<include file="$(find project_gazebo)/urdf/pioneer3at_kinect.xml" />

  <node name="spawn_p3dx" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot_description -x -0.0 -y -0.0 -z 0.051" respawn="false" output="screen" />

</launch>
```

My model file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
   xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
   xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
   xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"
>

<!-- Chassis -->
<link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
        <mass value="15.0"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.10"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.3338" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
             iyy="0.4783" iyz="0.0"
             izz="0.3338"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="base_visual">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.177" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
            <mesh filename="package://project_gazebo/meshes/p3at_meshes/chassis.stl"/>
        </geometry>
                   <material name="ChassisRed">
            <color rgba="0.851 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                   </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.177" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://project_gazebo/meshes/p3at_meshes/chassis.stl"/>
            </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <visual>
      <material>
        <script>
          <name value="Gazebo/Red"/>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

And the Gazbeo look like:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15845/bug-with-colors-loading-from-xacro-in-gazebo-7/) by [eed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3159/eed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) on 2017-04-12**:
it works in my gazebo 7.0.0. Are you sure you wrote the link name correctly?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-04-12**:
What's the output look like with the --verbose argument given to gazebo? If you're launching gazebo with roslaunch the arg atribute can be used to provide it http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

**Comment by [eed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3159/eed/) on 2017-04-13**:
the link name is corrct. It worked in ros-indigo and gazebo 2

@sloretz what exactly you mean can I just add "<extra_gazebo_args value="verbose" />" to the launch file? I posted my launch file above

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-04-13**:
empty_world.launch in gazebo_ros allows enabling verbose with either  or

**Comment by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) on 2017-04-13**:
It won't help him much,though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Seems to be a bug in sdformat. When converting from urdf to sdf, material property is omitted in some occasions due to name mangling and link reduction. I'm digging it further.

**Remove `name` attribute from your `visual` tag**

**UPD**:
And here they are:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issues/132/parser-does-not-handle-urdf-material

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issues/86/incorrect-urdf-to-sdf-parsing-materials

**UPD**:
remove `name` attribute from your `visial` tag

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3159/eed/) on 2017-04-19**:
That worked for me. Thanks!